# <filename>.php trouble in mac os x yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am new to php, apache and mac os x.

In "httpd.conf" I have removed the "#" and have typed the command to restart the Apache server.

How do I make sure that PHP is in fact enabled?

I have a file called "h.php" containing:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

"h.php" is stored in "sites" (lowercase "s") on the root ("/sites").

What do I have to do to make my php files show the information they are supposed to and not the source code?

Thanks

Comment: If you are new then save yourself some time/trouble and install (M)AMP where A - apache, M - mysql, P - PHP. There should be more of them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving "h.php" to "/library/webserver/documents" and accessing it via "localhost/h.php"